# Process Builder Flow fails when using BulkAPI

Tags: process-builder, bulk-api

I have created a simple flow in Process Builder. The flow works fine for all scenarios that I test manually by updating Objects. However, when I use the BulkAPI with a large amount of records (100+) I start getting failures in the BulkAPI. The FlowApplication reports this error:

```
Error Occurred: UPDATE --- UPDATE FAILED --- ERRORS : (ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK) Record rolled back because not all records were valid and the request was using AllOrNone header --- for SFDC record with ID : 003A000001i6DGQIA2,
```

If I go to any of these SFDC records e.g. 003A000001i6DGQIA2 and simply do an update to spawn the Flow again, it works without issue.

Im a little unsure how to diagnose this further. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would try to use the bulk API with just 2 records: the one that failed and another one. You need to narrow down the conditions that cause the issue. If that does not throw the error, gradually increase the number of records (I would try 2x every time) until you find out exactly what record(s) trigger it. Is there a nested exception somewhere?